# Let VS Extension jump to line of code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a VS extension to scan the currently opened solution / projects for some rules in xaml code.

For now the xaml files are simply processed as an `XDocument`. The rule violations are shown in a `ListView` from where I can open the related `ProjectItem` on click.

How can I extend this to rebuild the behaviour of VS's `Find All` where a click opens the related file and automatically jumps to the appropriate line and position in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have opened the file, use **EnvDTE.TextSelection.MoveToLineAndOffset** method:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
ts.MoveToLineAndOffset(line, column);
```